# WPF Material Design MenuItems with Image

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, menu, material-design

I'm writing a program in C# WPF with XAML Material Design, 
my program should support many languages.

```
<Menu IsMainMenu="True" DockPanel.Dock="Right" >
       <MenuItem Header="Language" materialDesign:ColorZoneAssist.Background="Aqua">
            <MenuItem Header="English" Icon"...">
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Russian" Icon"...">
            </MenuItem>
       </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

In this code, I only can add already defined **icons** by Material Design to MenuItem,
But I'd like to add a small flag **image** to before the text **English**, **Russian** etc...

I tried to add a **StackPanel** into a **MenuItem**, but it doesn't work:(

I would appreciate any help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help.

```
<Menu IsMainMenu="True" DockPanel.Dock="Right" >
        <MenuItem Header="Language">
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Width="20" Height="20" Source="Images/Languages.jpg"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </MenuItem.Icon>

            <MenuItem Header="English">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Width="20" Height="20" Source="Images/English.jpg"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Russian">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Width="20" Height="20" Source="Images/Russian.jpg"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
```